# Parsing .txt file to generate .csv

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a text file with following contents

```
Torrent file  : Linux.Format.-.October.2016.-.True.Pdf.-.Set.1001.[ECLiPSE].torrent
Metadata info : 9968 bytes, 412 pieces, 65536 bytes per piece
Torrent name  : Linux Format - October 2016 - True Pdf - Set 1001 [ECLiPSE]
Content info  : 3 files, 26965176 bytes
Announce URL  : http://explodie.org:6969/announce

F#  Bytes       File name
--- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------
  1    26944026 linfor1016.pdf
  2       19963 ECLiPSE.txt
  3        1187 Read Me.txt

Torrent file  : linuxmint-13-cinnamon-dvd-64bit.iso.torrent
Metadata info : 32303 bytes, 1602 pieces, 524288 bytes per piece
Torrent name  : linuxmint-13-cinnamon-dvd-64bit.iso
Content info  : single file, 839909376 bytes
Announce URL  : http://torrents.linuxmint.com/announce.php
Torrent file  : linuxmint-13-kde-dvd-64bit.iso.torrent
Metadata info : 35938 bytes, 1784 pieces, 524288 bytes per piece
Torrent name  : linuxmint-13-kde-dvd-64bit.iso
Content info  : single file, 935329792 bytes
Announce URL  : http://torrents.linuxmint.com/announce.php
```

file is generated via

```
for i in *.torrent;do torrentcheck -t $i >> info.txt;done
```

Now I want to convert this txt file such that I get a csv file with **two columns**, namely *Torrent file* & *Content info* (as headers) for each torrent file parsed via above bash command like:

```
Torrent file,Content info 
Linux.Format.-.October.2016.-.True.Pdf.-.Set.1001.[ECLiPSE].torrent,3 files, 26965176 bytes
linuxmint-13-cinnamon-dvd-64bit.iso.torrent,single file, 839909376 bytes
linuxmint-13-kde-dvd-64bit.iso.torrent,single file, 935329792 bytes
```

the columns can then be further processed in any Spreadsheet application to sort torrents by their size or by the number of files in them...

I can search for file strings like

```
grep 'Torrent file' info.txt or grep 'Content' info.txt
```

but how do I play with the return text strings to extract required info like if I get `Torrent file  : linuxmint-13-cinnamon-dvd-64bit.iso.torrent` I can use Spreadsheet MID,LEN commands to reduce string to just `linuxmint-13-cinnamon-dvd-64bit.iso.torrent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple awk script can parse the data, eg:

```
awk -F': ' 'BEGIN { print "Torrent file,Content info,Size" }
$0~/^Torrent file/ { save = $2 }
$0~/^Content info/ { printf "%s,%s\n",save,$2 }'  <info.txt
```

Split the lines on ": ", save the 2nd field of one line, print it later when the other line is found.

Comment: You could roll this into a 'oneliner' ala `echo "Torrent file,Content info" > info.csv && cat info.txt | awk -F': ' '$1=="Torrent file  " { save = $2 } $1=="Content info  " { printf "%s,%s\n",save,$2 }' >> info.csv`

Comment: thnx for replying, however your oneliner solution is outputting only the first line that is `Torrent file,Content info` nothing else  ..I am running your command after cd'ing to directory containing info.txt

Comment: @nightcrawler I edited my answer to be less fussy with the number of spaces before the ":", and begin with the column header. Perhaps that helps. With this pattern the `T` of Torrent must be the first character on the line, with no intervening spaces, for example.

Comment: I don't know is it my bash alone ..however your original answer (separated lines) did work ..and tinkering finally I got this to work `echo "Torrent file,Content info" > info.csv && cat info.txt | awk -F': ' ' $1=="Torrent file  " { save = $2 } $1=="Content info  " { printf "%s,%s\n",save,$2 }' >> info.csv
`